# Server Status Accessiblility

Tags: centos5

I'm using Centos 5.

Where can I upload an index.php server status file on the server to make it www accessible via http://serverIP/index.php method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be /var/www/html by default.

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-apache-config-ui.html

Make sure you have php installed and configured.